# MouseHover Styling in Hyperlinks

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have hyperlinks that i want to change color on Mouse hover to show that they are responsive and get rich user interface but i am not able to achieve this..

Here is the fiddle..
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z45Xz/)

And Here is the HTML...

```
<div id="footer" class="footer-shadow">
<div style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:960px; ">
    <div id="footerAboutUS" style="float:left; width:150px; position:relative;  margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 7px;">
        <label style="font-size:18px; color: #6c3f00;">About US</label>
        <br/> <a href="#" style="color: gray;text-decoration:none;font-size: 11px;">Our Delivery Model</a>

        <br/> <a href="#" style="color: gray;text-decoration:none;font-size: 11px;">Solution Area</a>

        <br/> <a href="#" style="color: gray;text-decoration:none;font-size: 11px;">List of Industries</a>

        <br/> <a href="#" style="color: gray;text-decoration:none;font-size: 11px;">IT Management</a>

        <br/> <a href="#" style="color: gray;text-decoration:none;font-size: 11px;">Lines of Business</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to avoid the inline styles added to HTML elements to make sure that the external styles are applying correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a different color on mouse over using 'hover' pseudo class of CSS.

Example:

```
.footer-shadow a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z45Xz/1/

Answer (score 2):

try to remove the a lement style attribute that overriding your css 
then then use  tag as below

```
<style>
    a {
        color: gray;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 11px;
    }

        a:hover {
            color: red;
        }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use class in place of style

like :

`.class1{`

`color: gray;`

`text-decoration:none;`

`font-size: 11px;`

`}`

and change color on hover like

`.class1:hover{`

`color: blue;`

`text-decoration:none;`

`font-size: 11px;`

`}`

Answer (score 1):

First, remove color gray from your `a` elements (In you html file). Then insert this into your css:

```
a {
    color: gray;
}

a:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

With demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RubberPoint/d9n79/

Answer (score 1):

First, Don't use inline style for `<a>` tag as `color: gray;`.                                     because if you use inline style ,you can't override the another style (internal,external).

```
a{

color: gray; //you can add your more style here
}
```

and for mouse change over use this.

```
a:hover{

color: blue; //you can add your more style here
}
```

Otherwise, use some ID or class for html element to avoid generic changes for all `<a>` tag

Answer (score 1):

Just add `:hover` selector and add `!important` rule to override the current style

Check this link: http://jsfiddle.net/z45Xz/4/

```
.footer-shadow a:hover{
   color: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing as mentioned in above answers Don't use inline style.
And just

```
a{
color:grey;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

and for changing the color when u hover the mouse use psedo class "hover" like

```
a:hover
{
color:green;
}
```